# Error including jquery-ui/autocomplete

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm currently trying to get auto-complete to work with my rails app, however when I try to load a page I get the error below.

```
couldn't find file 'jquery-ui/autocomplete' with type 'application/javascript'
```

I am currently included the following files in applcation.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui/autocomplete
//= require autocomplete-rails
```

And have included the files below in my GEM file

```
gem 'rails-jquery-autocomplete'
gem "jquery-rails"
gem "jquery-ui-rails"
```

I am currently following the guide at https://github.com/bigtunacan/rails-jquery-autocomplete, and can't figure out why I am getting this error. Could anyone provide some insight into what might be going on?